# Website Performance testing measures

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, response-time

I have a MVC application hosted in a Server and I want to measure the performance of it for each request.

I have got several online testing tools and I could not find a way to get the below measures in a single tool.

1. The time between the user clicks on the link in the browser and the request hits the Server.
2. The request process time in the server.
3. Response framing time in the server.
4. Response download time in the browser.

I agree that

1. the 1st and the 4th can be obtained from the several online tools and even from firebug.
2. the 2nd and 3rd can be obtained from the IIS Logs - Time Taken.

But is there any tool available which would consolidate all these measures in one single place ?

Thanks,

R. Venkatesan

Answer (score 0):

you should use

**[testing tool for speed]** https://gtmetrix.com/[1](https://gtmetrix.com/)